# Is there any reason to root for developing apps?

Tags: android, root

Just as the question says. I was curious because my development phone will also be my everyday phone (Galaxy S2) so of course I would want to be sure I'm voiding my warranty for a good reason.

Is it also simple to reverse roots without bricking the phone. Will unrooting be detectable, or will it look as it did beforehand? Also, what does unrooting do to installed apps that require root? Are they merely unable to launch until the phone is rooted again?

Comment: We have questions from a user perspective on the advantages of rooting, so I'm going to migrate this to [SO] (we don't handle dev questions).  eldarerathis gave a good answer despite that, though!

Comment: Thanks for the edit as well, though I'm adding one of my own since you removed some of the question I wanted answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have two phones that I use when developing at work: my personal phone (an EVO) and a phone my employer bought (a Fascinate). I spend most of my time developing and testing on my EVO because it's rooted. The main thing that you lose without root is that you can't access `/data`, which can be a pain when debugging. Root also lets you easily install busybox from the Market, which contains a lot of useful tools (like `grep` and `cp`).

As an example: if you save any data to your app's default file directory, it will live in `/data/data/<package_name>/files`. Trying to debug an issue when loading data that's stored in a file gets hugely obnoxious when you can't actually *see* the contents of the file, but you won't have permission to view it without root. The same is true of any databases that you create for an app (they live in `/data/data/<package_name>/databases` by default).

So in my personal/professional opinion, it's helpful to have at least one rooted device for development so that you can access files and directories you would otherwise not have permission to see.

Comment: As of note /data/local is user-writable but it's not where your application's files will normally go. You could put busybox there on a non-rooted phone (it's part of the root process for some phones)

Comment: @Broam: I don't know of any busybox installers in the Market which work without root, though (are there any?)

Comment: If you don't have root you can still get to the files in the apps directory i.e. /data/data/ just not from the phone. YOu need to use the adb command from the command prompt from the Android SDK

Comment: @Boardy: No, you can't. `adb pull` will tell you `permission denied` when you try to get a file from `/data` with the exception of `/data/local`. `adb shell` will let you `cd` into `/data`, but `ls` and other commands will tell you permission is denied as well.

Answer (score 2):

eldarerathis has sufficiently answered your title question, I think, so let me address the rest.

The Galaxy S II is quite easy to unroot, largely because of a tool called Odin.  You can flash the original unrooted firmware easily and blow away everything currently on the phone (see [this XDA guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1110160&highlight=odin)). It can be unrooted via other methods that leave all of your data and apps intact, as well (see [this root/unroot method over on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1125414&highlight=unroot)).

Unrooting does absolutely nothing to apps that use root.  Some will fail, some will tell you they can't be used, others will work until you try to do something that requires root.  They can all be launched, since launching doesn't require root.